# How to make a circle slowly appear in the shape of a circle in a clockwise direction?

Tags: animation, mesh, particles, animation-nodes, effects

I am making a doctor strange portal in blender 2.82, I want the portal to slowly animate in, in the shape of a circle, such that the portal appears slowly in a clockwise direction, just the way Dr Strange's portal appears. How do I do it?

Comment: Hello, for the moment it's a little bit vague, you should show some pictures and tell how realistic you want it to be

Comment: Hi. You've tagged this with `animation-nodes`. Is that because you specifically want to use animation nodes to do this?

Comment: Nah, not specifically, I just want it to happen one way or the other.

Comment: I would like it semi realistic (Magic isn't real anyway). I want it to open just the way Dr. Strange's portal opens, and am sorry, I don't know how to add pictures.

Comment: For those of us that have never watched the show you mention. Can you edit your question and add a reference image?